# strange issue on Magento 1.7.0.0

Tags: php, ubuntu, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

My website is not work okay, I check the console and all my js files have this error:

```
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/mage/cookies.js"<br/>
> cookies.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/prototype/prototype.js"<br/>
> prototype.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/scriptaculous/effects.js"<br/>
> effects.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/lib/ccard.js"<br/>
> ccard.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"<br/>
> dragdrop.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/prototype/validation.js"<br/>
> validation.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/scriptaculous/controls.js"<br/>
> controls.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/scriptaculous/builder.js"<br/>
> builder.js<br/>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.exapmple.com/%7Bunsecure_base_url%7D%7Djs/scriptaculous/slider.js"<br/>
```

what can be? maybe `%7D` is a server encoding issue? How I can solve this?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: you forgot a `{` in your template so your code didn't output the unsecure_base_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot a `{` in your field so magento didn't output the unsecure_base_url value but the variable name and the encoded brackets

```
 {{unsecure_base_url}}
```

Comment: thank you I just edit my post, to see my admin panel